# Can a converter being used in a Source of a Binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

```
Text="{Binding MyTextProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                            AncestorType=local:MyUserControl}}"
```

in the above code, i can get the `MyUserControl` as my source but the `MyTextProperty` is in another control which inside the `MyUserControl`. so i can use a converter and get the 'MyUserControl' and return the corresponding control as Source.

is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could expose the inner control as a public property in MyUserControl:

```
public class MyUserControl
{
    public MyInnerControl InnerControl { get; set; }
}
```

and use it in the property path of your binding like this:

```
Text="{Binding InnerControl.MyTextProperty,
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:MyUserControl}}"
```